# DAX to get previous month quantity in a 4-5-4 context (without time intelligence formulas)

Tags: dax

**Thanks to the help of @Sam Nseir , i am adding additional info right here to put my post in context. it was my lack of understanding of what some of the filter context was

My new revised formula for [PREV PERIOD ACTUAL QUANTITY] now looks like this: (note the placement of "MAX" , "ALL" , and a lack of "KEEPFILTERS"

```
A REV PREV PERIOD ACTUAL = 
VAR CurrentYearMonth = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] )
VAR PreviousYearMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] ),
        ALL ( 'CALENDAR' ),
        'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] < CurrentYearMonth
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM('LOT HIERARCHY JOIN'[Actual Qty]),
        'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] = PreviousYearMonth,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( 'CALENDAR' )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

I then can take this revised number and input it into my average inventory calculation
`Average Inventory EOP = ([Prev Period Actual Qty]+[QTY AVAIL])/2`

Which is then used in days of supply (the days count measure is counting the days in a calendar month since 4-5-4 uses 28 day or 35 day months....)
 `DOS  = [Average Inventory EOP]/SUM('STOW SHIP FILES'[QUANTITY_SHIPPED])*[DAYS COUNT 4-5-4]`

---

I use 4-5-4 calendar data and Im still feeling my way through this. I have several files brought into my query for essentially units on-hand in a warehouse. These come every month for two different warehouses. I then have that connected in the data model to my other query of units distributed out of each warehouse ("stow ship files"). The end number I arrive at is essentially a days-of-supply (i.e. this:
`[Average Inventory EOP]/SUM('STOW SHIP FILES'[QUANTITY_SHIPPED])*[DAYS COUNT 4-5-4]`)

I have a few columns such as "YEAR-MONTH NUMBER" etc in my imported calendar. Yes it has calendar year dates, but all of the other reporting year type data such as fiscal day number/month number/week number/ etc as you'd find in 4-5-4 context.

I started this quest looking for a way to simply get PREVIOUS MONTH units on-hand from the report without being able to use the fancy DAX time intelligence functions, since you cant with 4-5-4 or week-based calendars. I stumbled upon this solution [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/comparing-with-previous-selected-time-period-in-dax/) on SQLBI and it works fine. Trouble is, this "previous period actual quantity" measure goes blank whenever I try to filter any of the follow on measures and I cant figure out why.

So first step is using the above snippet for "previous period actual" AKA last month's units:

```
Prev Period Actual Qty = 
VAR CurrentYearMonth = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] )
VAR PreviousYearMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'CALENDAR' ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] < CurrentYearMonth )
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM('LOT HIERARCHY JOIN'[Actual Qty]),
        'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] = PreviousYearMonth,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( 'CALENDAR' )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

I then input this resulting "previous period actual" into my average inventory formula. AKA previous period's closing number + current period's closing number "qty avail", divided by 2.
`Average Inventory EOP = ([Prev Period Actual Qty]+[QTY AVAIL])/2`

Then, I divide that by the quantity the warehouse ships out, which gets multiplied by the number of days in the 4-5-4 month:
`A DOS REVISED = [Average Inventory EOP]/SUM('STOW SHIP FILES'[QUANTITY_SHIPPED])*[DAYS COUNT 4-5-4]`

I have a graphic that then graphs the days of supply by each business area contained on the report (aka like departments). This works fine if I dont touch any filters. But when I try to produce my desired filter of "any [DOS] greater than 90 days" , it blanks out that measure [PREVIOUS PERIOD ACTUAL QUANTITY] and im sure this is due to some misunderstanding of filter context I have.

I would be happy to provide any more info or clarifying remarks. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share how your desired filter of "any [DOS] greater than 90 days" is implemented?

Comment: Sam, i am just implementing that criteria via the filters pane. I make a column chart, and it shows all of the lines of business accurately . But as soon as I start to manipulate the measure of DOS, it goes blank. Or, I try to filter the column chart to show just one month or anything outside that full range of data, i can see it doing weird math on the results because now, the "previous period actual" measure that goes into other formulas, turns blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECTEDVALUE` will return blank if more than one distinct value is present. I suspect with your filtering, more than one `'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM]` is present.

Try switching it to:

```
VAR CurrentYearMonth = MAX( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] )
// or to
VAR CurrentYearMonth = MIN( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] )
```

Depending if you want to show the previous first or last month in range of the filter.

And also update `var PreviousYearMonth` to:

```
VAR PreviousYearMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] ),
        ALL ( 'CALENDAR' ),
        'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] < CurrentYearMonth
    )
```

---

Additional ask below about comparing previous non-continuous month.

```
Prev Period Diff (selected) = 
VAR CurrentYearMonth = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] )
VAR PreviousYearMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'CALENDAR' ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( 'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] < CurrentYearMonth )
    )
VAR PreviousResult =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM('LOT HIERARCHY JOIN'[Actual Qty]),
        'CALENDAR'[YEAR MONTH NUM] = PreviousYearMonth
    )
RETURN
    IF(NOT ISBLANK(PreviousYearMonth), SUM('LOT HIERARCHY JOIN'[Actual Qty]) - PreviousResult )
```

[image]

Comment: So changing to MAX, it seems to have preserved the behavior on my main data table visual, and still worked. But once again, as soon as I filter to any level, I am losing that "previous period actual" number entirely. Hence, my DOS is now adding zero to the quantity shipped, so its cutting everything into a fraction of what it should be... 

Is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Updated answer to include change to `PreviousYearMonth`. From `ALLSELECTED` to `ALL`. Out of interest, what format is `[YEAR MONTH NUM]`? Can you subtract 1 from it?

Comment: I will try your update. YEAR MONTH NUM is just numbering the fiscal year and period. Since ours is 4-5-4, we start the year in feb. so february 2023 is 202301 (I put a leading zero so that the sort can work properly). I did this in a column in my data import in Powe Query. October is 202309 and so on. So yes, you could subtract by one to get previous month....but what do you do when its Feb of 2024 aka 202401 and you want to get previous month 202312 ?

Comment: Sam I think this may have done the trick!! can you explain your updates to var Previous year month and why it behaves "correct" now when using any kind of filters? really want to learn the magic behind the curtain here....

Comment: `ALL` returns the whole table/column ignoring internal and external filters. Where `ALLSELECTED` only ignores the internal filters, that is filters from within the visual. So in your case `ALLSELECTED` would never find anything outside the filtered range.

Comment: great! one more thing.... so the solution I was able to find and insert into my use-case, was for a scenario where you might want your visuals/measure to display the difference from non-contiguous date ranges. i.e. if I have december, june, january as the only months selected, then you see the difference as if those months were right next to eachother. How might you treat this if I wanted it to always truly be for contiguous "year-month" relationships? it may be moot and best not kick the bear..... since I know Ill always have contiguous files/months however.....

Comment: Then this is the case to use both `SELECTEDVALUE` together with `ALLSELECTED`. You would use `SELECTEDVALUE` to give you Dec, then do pretty much what you had and get the next prev month in `ALLSELECTED`. If none then you are the start of the range. And then over to Jan, it will find Dec then you can do your diff, and so on. Or you could use the Waterfall visual and let it handle it for you. If you are good with your main question being answered, please help accept for the benefit of all.

Comment: I've updated the answer above and included `Prev Period Diff (selected)` for comparing the previous month continuous or not.

Comment: Sam, if I wanted to extend that prev month's formula to now include not just previous month, but also the one before it (an attempt to get me a rolling 3 period average inventory), how might I manipulate that?

So instead of just Actual quantity for current month + prev period actual / 2 , it would be actual qty current month + previous period actual + two periods ago / 3.

Comment: I would cheat and add year-month index to your Calendar table. For example: `MonthIndex = [Year] * 13 + [MonthNum]` (13 months in 4-5-4 right?). Then you can do minus 2 on SLEECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[MonthIndex])`

Comment: No it is still 12, and mine begins in February and ends in January of next calendar year. So january of 2024 is technically period 12 and thus referred to "january 2023" in reporting context..... i love the confusion....

Comment: Okay, so you can still do the above but with `YEAR` * 12 + MONTHNUM` to give you an index. And with that that index you can add/subtract from your current index. It would simplify your expressions quite a bit.

Comment: got it! [two_months_ago]
VAR CurrentYearMonth = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'CALENDAR'[MonthIndex] )
VAR twomonthsago =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'CALENDAR'[MonthIndex] ),
        ALL ( 'CALENDAR' ),
        'CALENDAR'[MonthIndex] = CurrentYearMonth-2
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM('LOT HIERARCHY JOIN'[Actual Qty]),
        ('CALENDAR'[MonthIndex]) = twomonthsago,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( 'CALENDAR' )
    )
RETURN

Comment: It could be **much** simpler `VAR twomonthsago = CurrentYearMonth - 2`